# How to fix button to be interacted with, in carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, carousel, grommet

When I try to import a layer/button onto one of these cards it does not allow it to be clicked or interacted with. I believe the problem is with the carousel. What is a way I can fix this? The "CenterLayer" is supposed to act as a button and is the one I am having problems with. When I put this code the layer appears on the card as a footer but it's not allowed to be clicked. Is there anyone that can help me with this, please?

```html
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  Box,
  Image,
  Heading,
  Carousel,
  Grommet,
  Calendar,
  Text,
} from "grommet";
import {CenterLayer} from "./EventsButton";

import { MainFooter } from "../Footer/Footer";


const Card0 = () => (
  <Card pad="large" background="dark-1" gap="medium">
   <CardHeader>
   <Box height="small" width="small">
   <Image src="./images/Photo.jpg" />
   </Box>
   </CardHeader>
   <CardBody>The Stranahan High School Graduation</CardBody>
   <Box direction="row" round gap="xlarge">
   <CardFooter>
   3/25/2021
   </CardFooter>
   <CardFooter>
   <CenterLayer />
   </CardFooter>
    </Box>
          
  </Card>
);

const Card1 = () => (
<Card pad="large" background="dark-1" gap="medium">
<CardHeader>
 <Box height="small" width="small">
  <Image src="./images/Photo.jpg" />
</Box>
</CardHeader>
<CardBody>Card1 The Stranahan High School Graduation</CardBody>
<CardFooter>Footer</CardFooter>
</Card>
);

const Card2 = () => (
<Card pad="large" background="dark-1" gap="medium">
<CardHeader>
<Box height="small" width="small">
<Image src="./images/Photo.jpg" />{" "}
</Box>
</CardHeader>
<CardBody>Card2 The Stranahan High School Graduation</CardBody>
<CardFooter>Footer</CardFooter>
</Card>
);


const Events = () => (
<Grommet>
    
<Heading textAlign="center" size="large" alignSelf="center" level="2" margin={{ left: "xlarge",
top: "large",}}>Upcoming Events</Heading>
<Carousel>
<Box direction="row" pad="large" round gap="small">
<Card0 />
<Card1 />
<Card2 />
</Box>
<Box direction="row" pad="large" round gap="small">
<Card1 />
<Card0 />
<Card2 />
</Box>
<Box direction="row" pad="large" round gap="small">
<Card2 />
<Card1 />
<Card0 />
</Box>
<Box direction="row" pad="large" round gap="small">
<Card1 />
<Card0 />
<Card2 />
</Box>
</Carousel>

<Heading textAlign="center" size="large" alignSelf="center" level="2" margin={{ left: "xlarge",
top: "large",}}>Past Events</Heading>
<Carousel>
<Box direction="row" pad="large" round gap="small">
<Card0 />
<Card1 />
<Card2 />
</Box>
<Box direction="row" pad="large" round gap="small">
<Card1 />
<Card0 />
<Card2 />
</Box>
<Box direction="row" pad="large" round gap="small">
<Card2 />
<Card1 />
<Card0 />
</Box>
<Box direction="row" pad="large" round gap="small">
 <Card1 />
<Card0 />
<Card2 />
</Box>
</Carousel>

    
<Box direction="row" pad="xlarge" round gap="xlarge">
<Box height="medium" width="medium" margin={{left: "xlarge"}}>
<Calendar fill daysOfWeek />
</Box>
<Box margin={{left: "xlarge", top:"large"}}>
<Card background={'orange'} >
<CardBody height="medium" width="medium" margin={{right: "medium", bottom: "medium", left: "medium", top: "medium"}}> 
<Text>At SEEF we take every opportunity to help the Stranahan community. We hope that our impact will lead others to do the same.</Text>
</CardBody>
</Card>
</Box>
</Box>  
< MainFooter />


</Grommet>

);



export default Events
```

```html
import React from 'react';

import { Add } from 'grommet-icons';

import { Box, Button, Grommet, Heading, Layer, Select, Text } from 'grommet';
import { grommet } from 'grommet/themes';

export const CenterLayer = () => {
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState();
const onOpen = () => setOpen(true);
const onClose = () => setOpen(undefined);



return (
    <Grommet theme={grommet} >
    <Box fill align="center" justify="center">
        <Button
        icon={<Add />}
        label={
            <Text>
            <strong>More Information</strong>
            </Text>
        }
        onClick={onOpen}
        plain
        />
    </Box>
    {open && (
        <Layer position="center" onClickOutside={onClose} onEsc={onClose}>
        <Box pad="medium" gap="small" width="medium">
            <Heading level={3} margin="none">
            The Stranahan High School Graduation
            </Heading>
            <Text>This event will be taken place at City Hall in Fort Lauderdale</Text>
            <Text>This event will be taken place on 3/25/2021 at 3:00PM</Text>
            <Box
            as="footer"
            gap="small"
            direction="row"
            align="center"
            justify="end"
            pad={{ top: 'medium', bottom: 'small' }}
            >
            
            <Button
                label={
                <Text color="white">
                    <strong>Close</strong>
                </Text>
                }
                onClick={onClose}
                primary
                color="status-critical"
            />
            </Box>
        </Box>
        </Layer>
    )}

    </Grommet>
);
};

CenterLayer.storyName = 'Center';

CenterLayer.parameters = {
chromatic: { disable: true },
};

export default {
title: 'EventsButton',
};
```

Comment: The code you shared isn't working and it is not clear what you were trying to do. Please place the button or put an explanation what is the expected functionality.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry about that, I believe I fixed all the problems and hopefully, you can take a look at it again, please. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carousel is an interactive element, i.e. it has its own focus and navigation behavior, and for UX & accessibility reasons you shouldn't place nested interactive elements inside of each other, hence I'd try to avoid a button inside of a card, inside of a Carousel.

That being said, the button you've placed in the card is placed 'behind' the Carousel, so moving up its z-index would solve the problem.
Add this style to a Card and it should do trick

`<Card style={{ zIndex: "100" }} ... >`

I chose 100 as a random number, feel free to make it smaller according to your app behavior.